# onActivityResult() not called in fragment and activity finishes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment within an activity and I am using a button to select a notification sound using the ringtone picker:

```
selectSound.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            if (notification != null) {
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) notification);
            }
            Log.v("TASKS", "Starting Ringtone picker for reminders");

            startActivityForResult(intent, 5001);
        }
    });
```

Here's my onActivityResult in the fragment:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v("TASKS", "onActivityResult in ReminderSettings: " + requestCode);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 5001)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

        SharedPreferences settings =
            mActivity.getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = settings.edit();

        if (uri != null)
        {
            editor.putString("NOTIFICATION_SOUND", uri.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            editor.putString("NOTIFICATION_SOUND", null);
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

My activity has an onActivityResult but it does make call for unhandled results:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(
    int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ...
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The strange thing is after launching and selecting a ringtone neither onActivityResult in the fragment or the activity are called when I debug and the activity seems to finish - there is no force close or exception on the Logcat. I have tested this now on 2 different devices and I get the same result - I'm using ActionBarSherlock for fragments if thats relevant.

Comment: remove  this code and try once super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: please try handle onActivityResult in activity instead of fragment.

Comment: tryo to put your log before your call to `super`, and see if the `log` is being shown.

Comment: I've moved logging statements to first line of onActivityResult in both fragment and activity and debugged again and neither method is being called